# Keep chapter numbering of figures with endfloat

Tags: endfloat

I'm writing my thesis and using the `endfloat` package to put figures at the end. Is there a way of keeping the numbering system of `Figure X.1` where X is the number of the chapter the figure is defined in?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Is this possibly related to this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13491/using-endfloat-with-chapters-figure-x-about-here-has-incorrect-numbering ?

Comment: Thanks! From what I see in that question, it doesn't seem to be possible to preserve chapter numbering and have floats at the end of the document. That's a shame. Since I really need this behavior (from my advisor) can you recommend any way of getting it?

Comment: There is another approach over here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/406846/47927 I am not sure whether this can help you.

Comment: YES! It works! Thanks. I don't know if I you can put that in an answer so I mark it as answered.

Comment: It should rather be considered a duplicate, as this question already has been answered elsewhere. :)